# How to tell ant to build using a specific javac executable?

Tags: java, ant, build, executable, javac

How can I tell `ant` to use a specific javac executable from the command line?

I have an installation of gcj, built as part of gcc, within a library we distribute, and I'd like to have a particular piece of Java software built against that. However, it just seems to use the system-gcc, and options such as "-Dbuild.compiler" seem to want me to specify some kind of Java class rather than a filepath.

I was hoping for something similar to CC in Makefiles.

I'm sure it's something really simple, and I'm just being stupid.

---

To be clear, I'd like to avoid editing the build file myself if possible. Is there not some standard way to simply specify the compiler on the command-line to ant? I don't mind the assumption that the buildfile is "well-behaved" in some sense.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using Ant 1.6 or higher, you can set the `javac` attribute `fork="yes"`. This gives you the ability to specify the path of your executable when using jikes, jvc, gcj, sj, or whatever version of `javac` you are using.

```
  <javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         fork="yes"
         executable="/opt/java/jdk1.1/bin/javac"
         compiler="javac1.1"
  />
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but this is specifying the executable in the actual ant file, not at the command line

Comment: @bakoyaro. This easily solved using a property for the executable and then passing it from the command line with -D (e.g., -Dmyjavacpath=whatever will set the ${myjavacpath} variabile

Comment: @Matteo Please see my posted answer for this question.

Answer (score 8):

The `-D` argument when calling ant will use a property from the command line inside of the Ant script. The form that it is used in is:

`ant -Dmyvar=true`

Where `myvar` is the name of the property, and `true` is the value you want to use in your script.

The easiest way then would be to use a property for your javac executable attributes.

```
 <target name="compile">  
   <javac srcdir="${src}"
     destdir="${build}"
     fork="${fork}"
     executable="${javac.executable}"
     compiler="${compiler}"/>  
 </target>
```

and then on the command line you could call:

```
ant compile -Djavac.executable=/usr/bin/local/jdk/javac -Dsrc=/home/src -Dbuild=/home/build -Dcompiler=javac1.6 -Dfork=true
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [javac task page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html):

> It is possible to use different compilers. This can be specified by
> either setting the global build.compiler property, which will affect
> all  tasks throughout the build, by setting the compiler
> attribute, specific to the current  task or by using a nested
> element of any typedeffed or componentdeffed type that implements
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapter. Valid values
> for either the build.compiler property or the compiler attribute are:
>
> - `classic` (the standard compiler of JDK 1.1/1.2) – javac1.1 and javac1.2 can be used as aliases.
> - `modern` (the standard compiler of JDK 1.3/1.4/1.5/1.6/1.7) – javac1.3 and javac1.4 and javac1.5 and javac1.6 and javac1.7 (since Ant 1.8.2) can be used as aliases.
> - `jikes` (the Jikes compiler).
> - `jvc` (the Command-Line Compiler from Microsoft's SDK for Java / Visual J++) – microsoft can be used as an alias.
> - `kjc` (the kopi compiler).
> - `gcj` (the gcj compiler from gcc).
> - `sj` (Symantec java compiler) – symantec can be used as an alias.
> - `extJavac` (run either modern or classic in a JVM of its own).

The way I read this, you need to write a class that implements CompilerAdapter and uses your compiler. Then typedef that task and use it in the javac compiler attribute.

Comment: Actually, as I understand, `gcj` support is already built in. A new CompilerAdapter would only be necessary for using another compiler not in the list.

Comment: After I have set it to gcj, can I then specifically provide the path to the gcj executable somehow? I don't want to use the system-wide gcj.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similiar before, using the Ant Exec task. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

It allows you to call a specific system command. In our case, we needed to call Delphi (don't ask) to build some DLL's for a particular project. The exec command would also allow you to call gcj instead of javac.

Comment: The fork="yes" option seems to be a lot cleaner. Live and learn!