# javac fork mode

Tags: javac

I am working on a project and saw the following configuration with a comment in a properties file.

```
# Forking just invokes the JVM externally, and doesn't exhibit any performance benefit.

javac.fork.mode=no
```

I am curious about what this means.
After several google searches, I still can't find a specific article about this. Could someone point me to a good resource?

Comment: I suppose this is a configuration for some build system, and evaluated by another part of your project. Search in your project files for other occurrences of `javac.fork.mode`.

Answer (score 1):

An option from the ant's `<javac>` task.

When fork=true ant will run the java-Compiler in it's own jvm.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Answer (score 1):

Forking allows javac to run as external process in its own heap space thus limits the memory leak to external process without affecting the parent java process.

Check the thread below which tells other options to be used along with 'fork' if you are using 'javac' Ant task.

[How to tell ant to build using a specific javac executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832298/how-to-tell-ant-to-build-using-a-specific-javac-executable)