# javac class not found when compiling with ant

Tags: java, ant

So I installed java 7 and javac this way on my Centos6.4

```
rpm -Uvh /path/to/binary/jdk-7u45-linux-x64.rpm
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac 200000
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45"
```

So I have:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45
$ ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on August 24 2010
```

Here is the error I get when compiling:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/project/build.xml:413: Class not found: javac1.7
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Does your JAVA_HOME points to version 1.7?

Comment: yes. please see the export command above.

Comment: ant 1.8.2 supports that aliased compilation target. You may need to follow the suggestion [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832298/how-to-tell-ant-to-build-using-a-specific-javac-executable), if you can't get a newer version of ant.

Comment: Excellent, it works fine with ant 1.8.2 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Petesh said, ant 1.8.2 supports aliased compilation target.